# Extend async tasks from base class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have two async classes in my application which you can see below

```
class RegisterTokenAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

and

```
class AuthenticateTokenAsync extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, String>
```

now I want to create one other **Base** class and extends this two classes from that base class, but I can't understand how I can do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Java(also in android)` Doesn't support `Multiple inheritance` so you cant extend two class.

you can Use `Multilevel inheritance`.

Like as,,

```
class A{}

class B extends A{}

class C extends B{}
```

Or there are also `Interface`,that can help....

Comment: Can you bring more detail example please.

Comment: i give all detail try to search inheritance and abstraction in java

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support multiple inheritance. What is it that you wish to abstract to the base class?

Perhaps declaring an interface would help? Then the two classes can implement the same interface.